# Access internal buffer, length and token match position of flex scanner

Tags: c++, flex-lexer

I am writing a scanner with flex to tokenize an text. For that I defined expressions that can match terms, numbers, emails, etc etc, literally all kind of occurrences that could be in a text.

I try to find a way how to access the internal scanner buffer containing the string to be parsed, the position (first character of an matched token) and the length (which would be `yyleng`).
First I thought I could handle that with a few variables and use yyleng, add this value to a variable keeping the start position in the parsed text of the match. But that would not work if between two matches is a large whitespace as there are ignored besides a few other occurrences like html tags or html entities, etc.

Is there any way I could work that out?

For example, following string:

```
I am a text,  tokenize   me.
^ ^  ^ ^   ^  ^          ^ ^
0 2  5 7   11 14         25 27   <-- pos in parsed string
0  2 1 4   1  8          2  1    <-- length of token
```

Each word, including punctuation would be matched, all whitespaces will be ignored. Now I would like to be able to get the starting position of each match in the string and the length. In my tokenizer class I would implement an *getNextToken* method, and each call to that method returning a token I like to get the start position, token length and the current input text (as a char buffer). I thought I could define a few functions for getting those values within the lexer file (as a kind od callback function or such).

Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: You could go through the generated code and see if there's any macros or functions or other global variables you could use.

Comment: I am already digging through the code and the generated class (#option c++ i use) is a mess as being not very readable. I guess most internals will be "private".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`yytext` points to the beginning of the token. If you use `yy_scan_buffer` (see the [flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Multiple-Input-Buffers.html)) then you flex will use the buffer you provide without copying it, so `yytext` will point into your buffer.

Note that you must put *two* NUL bytes at the end of the buffer you give flex, if you use the `yy_scan_buffer` interface. Also, you'll have to handle the case where a token spans two input buffers yourself. I'm not sure exactly how flex deals with tokens spanning input buffers in the case where you supply the buffer directly, but there's no obvious way that it could handle it while preserving the input buffer you provide.

Comment: yes, that sees to be a way. Thanks for that hint. I switched to `yy_scan_buffer()` and now I can get the current position with `strlen(yy_buf_pos)-yyleng`. I just wonder why the contents of of `yy_ch_buf` (input buffer) are the same as `yy_buf_pos` (the actual pointer to the cur. position while scanning). These are the interesting members of `yy_buffer_state`. I expected `yy_ch_buf` to have the complete input string as is. It seems to get modified too, probably is `yy_buf_pos` a copy of  `yy_ch_buf` using the same memory (alloced space)?!

Comment: Using `yy_buf_pos` is not advisable, since it is only updated occasionally (more or less, when you push the buffer state). It only accidentally holds the same value as `yy_ch_buf`. But you don't need the `strlen` at all; `yytext` points to the beginning of the token, and you can get the offset by subtracting the beginning of the buffer from it. You should know where the buffer starts without having to break into flex's private data.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the buffers. I also changed the offset calculation like you recommend, using pointers is even better.